Is it possible to continue an EWM after appending a row?
I have some quant finance code which does some analysis of stock prices.
One thing I need to calculate is an EWMA.
When doing research (ie: the historical "batch" world), I have a long list of stock prices, and I can use pandas ewm(...).mean() to calculate my EWMA over that list of prices.
Later, when using the same code in production (ie: the live "realtime" world), I want to calculate my EWMA for only the latest stock price, without having to recalculate the entire history.
Below is a walk through of the problem I'm facing:
Here is some code which simulates a stock price:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def gbm(T, N, mu, sigma, S0):        
    dt = float(T)/N
    t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
    W = np.random.standard_normal(size = N) 
    W = np.cumsum(W)*np.sqrt(dt) 
    X = (mu-0.5*sigma**2)*t + sigma*W 
    S = S0*np.exp(X)
    return S

dates = pd.date_range('2021-01-01', '2022-01-01')
T = (dates.max()-dates.min()).days / 365
N = len(dates)
mu = 0.03
sigma = 0.5
S0 = 100
df = pd.DataFrame(index=index, data={'value': gbm(T, N, mu, sigma, S0)}) 

I can calculate an EWMA over the data as follows:
df['ewma'] = df['value'].ewm(halflife=30).mean()
df.plot()


The tail of my dataframe looks as follows:

As is well known, the formula for calculating the EWMA is the previous EWMA value decayed by 1-α and the current observation scaled by α:

Now we pretend we're in the production, and we've just received a single new price. I add a single new observation to my source data:
df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=[pd.Timestamp('2022-01-02')], data={'value':105})
df = pd.concat([df, df_new])

The tail of my new dataframe looks as follows:

I would like to now calculate the EWMA of the new value.
Obviously I can just recalculate the entire history of the EWM over the entire dataframe:
df['ewma'] = df['value'].ewm(halflife=30).mean()

However, after benchmarking we have found this is a major bottleneck in our production pipeline.
I know that I can manually calulate the EWMA for the new value by manually calculating α from my halflife, and then using the EWMA formula with the previous EWMA value:
df = df.tail(2).copy()
halflife = 30
alpha = 1 - np.exp(-np.log(2)/halflife)
df.iloc[-1]['ewma'] = (1-alpha)*df.iloc[-2]['ewma'] + alpha*df.iloc[-1]['value']

However this causes a disconnect between what happens in the batch historical world.
My researchers write python code which uses pandas ewm(...).mean, and I want to take that code and productionise it, but not have to recalculate the entire history of the EWMA for every single price update.
I would like to present the researchers with a single unified interface which works in the historical batch world and in the live realtime world.
Is this possible with pandas?
Can I provide some state to pandas so that it "picks up where it left off" for the new value?

If I understand you correctly, you are concerned about why the dataframe only shows two lines.
I assume you are using the row:
df = df.tail(2).copy()

to set the value (delete this line). If we don't use this line, the value won't be set. And by using this line, you overwrite the dataframe and it becomes two rows long.
In any case, if you need a copy then:
df = pd.concat([df, df_new]).copy()

I also see a warning ChainedAssignmentError:
FutureWarning: ChainedAssignmentError: behaviour will change in pandas 3.0!
You are setting values through chained assignment. Currently this works in certain cases, but when using Copy-on-Write (which will become the default behaviour in pandas 3.0) this will never work to update the original DataFrame or Series, because the intermediate object on which we are setting values will behave as a copy.
A typical example is when you are setting values in a column of a DataFrame, like:

df["col"][row_indexer] = value

Use `df.loc[row_indexer, "col"] = values` instead, to perform the assignment in a single step and ensure this keeps updating the original `df`.

Don't use chained indexing, it won't update your data in new versions(3.0).
This is how it should work:
halflife = 30
alpha = 1 - np.exp(-np.log(2)/halflife)
df.loc[df.index[-1], 'ewma'] = (1-alpha)*df.loc[df.index[-2], 'ewma'] + alpha*df.loc[df.index[-1],'value']

Or if you need to calculate several new values. Then you need to save the date from which you need to calculate. For me, this is the data_calc variable.
Note that I created a comparison column to compare the last three ewma values ​​as they don't match at 3-4 decimal point.
df_new = pd.DataFrame(index=[pd.Timestamp('2022-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2022-01-03')
       , pd.Timestamp('2022-01-04')], data={'value':[105, 107, 110]})

df = pd.concat([df, df_new])

df['comparison'] = df['value'].ewm(halflife=30).mean()

data_calc = df_new.index[0]# Until what date do we calculate
df.loc[df.index < data_calc, 'ewma'] = df.loc[df.index < data_calc, 'value'].ewm(halflife=30).mean()

print(df)
print('there are no three indicator values at the end !!!!!!!!!!')

# New quotes have arrived
ind = df[df.index >= data_calc].index# data >= 2022-01-02

halflife = 30
alpha = 1 - np.exp(-np.log(2)/halflife)

def f(x):
       ind = df.index.get_loc(x.index[0])
       df.loc[df.index[ind], 'ewma'] = ((1 - alpha) * df.loc[df.index[ind - 1],
       'ewma'] + alpha * df.loc[df.index[ind], 'value'])

#calculate only three new values, calculation starts from the 
#new value (old ones are not recalculated)
df.loc[ind].groupby(ind).apply(f)

print(df)


No, I think you've misunderstood my question. Apologies if it was not clear enough. My concern is that we have two phases of operation, research and production. In research we are running large scale batch operations over historical data, and in this setting, pandas DataFrame.ewm is the go-to tool for calculating an EWMA. In production, we have a new update each minute, and here DataFrame.ewm with sufficient lookback is a bottleneck - I need to use an online EWMA calculation. My concern is the disconnect between research and production - there is no common interface.

'disconnect between research and production' I can't understand what it is (the problem), can you give an example to understand better?

I want my quants to be able to write the same code which can be used in both research and production. I want to be able to take their code which they've written to do their research over historical data, and have it work efficiently in production with streaming data. It would be ideal if pandas.DataFrame.ewm had the ability to record some internal state, such that if I call it repeatedly with new data, rather than having to re-calculate the entire lookback, it could pick up where it left off

As for calculating only on new data.
If adding new quote values ​​to the dataframe is not a problem?
Let's say you store a dataframe with quotes and ewm. Three new quotes appeared, you wrote them to the frame and passed the date of the first new value (data_calc), on the basis of which new indices (ind) are calculated, df.loc[ind].groupby(ind).apply(f) is launched and these three ewm values ​​are calculated. This is what I showed at the end. Simply pass the first index value of the new data to data_calc. Changed the code a little for understanding.

Unfortunately that approach is going to be really slow for large series of data in the non-streaming use case. So far I really haven't found a one-size-fits-all approach, and am leaning towards hand rolling my own C++ implementation and exposing it to python using pybind. It just seems so odd that there isn't something more ergonomic already, because it stands to reason this is a fairly common use case. I see pandas has OnlineExponentialMovingWindow, but it doesn't seem to cater very well to the batch case

If on history, then you can use pandas ewm. But there is a difference with the custom version in the 3-4 digit after the point. Perhaps something is not taken into account or there is a problem with float. Although if it is HFT, then adding one line will be slow.

That's literally the whole point of my question - I want to provider a common interface to my quants so that the code they write in research / for use over historical data doesn't have to be rewritten to work on streaming data. I am looking for one interface that works efficiently on historical data and streaming data
